# How can I upload an entire folder, that contains other folders, using sftp on linux?

Tags: linux, recursion, upload, console, sftp

I have tried `put -r directory/*`, which only uploaded the files and not folders. Gave me the error, cannot `Couldn't canonicalise`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try "put directory" without the slash and asterisk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084941/how-can-i-upload-an-entire-folder-that-contains-other-folders-using-sftp-on-li/44197588#44197588

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) you can find detailed explanation as how to copy a directory using `scp`. In your case, it would be something like:

```
$ scp -r foo your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/bar
```

This will copy the directory "foo" from the local host to a remote host's directory "bar". 
Here `-r` is -recursively copy entire directories.

You can also use `rcp` with similar syntax. The only difference between them is that `scp` uses secure shell and `rcp` uses remote shell.

**BTW** The "Couldn't canonicalise" error you mentioned appear when sftp server is unable to access the file/directory mentioned in the command.

**UPDATE**: For users who want to use `put` specifically, please refer to Ben Thielker answer here.

Comment: This won't work when the target only supports SFTP and not SSH.

Answer (score 230):

The answer is:

```
put -r local/path/to/directoryName
```

The uploaded directory must already exist in the working directory on the server, so you might need to create it first.

```
mkdir directoryName
```

Comment: when I try put -r somefile I get "invalid flag -r"

Comment: Thank you - somebody make this the accepted answer.

Comment: There should be a note for those poor users like myself who are not fortunate enough to be using a recent version of OpenSSH - recursive get and put were added in 5.4, those on CentOS or similar may be running an earlier version unless they have updated it manually.

Comment: Scouring for hours on the Internet and this is the only thing that I found that worked. Thank you Ben Thielker! 

What a time and lifesaver.

Comment: Slightly baffled as to why this answer has so many up votes. In the case of someone who needs to copy a directory with n sub dir and 2k files this answer is not helpful if i need to create each sub directory. This answer is not practical for every case.

Comment: The server I'm using doesn't allow SSH (only SFTP), so the accepted answer does not work for me (and thus does not actually answer the question...)

Answer (score 5):

```
sftp> mkdir source
sftp> put -r source
 Uploading source/ to /home/myself/source
 Entering source/
 source/file1
 source/file2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have issues using sftp, you can use ncftp
For centos

```
yum install ncftp
```

To copy a whole directory recursively

```
ncftpput -R -v -u username -P 21 ftp.server.dev /remote-path/ /localdirectory
```

Answer (score -11):

Use `scp` instead. It uses SSH too and can easily handle recursion.

Comment: `scp` is indeed superior, but not all `sftp` servers support `scp` connections, so `sftp` itself is sometimes required.

Comment: At the moment I'm in a C++ code base with sftp support but not scp support, and so this doesn't work for me either. scp is not always the answer.